# Python, issue with deepcopy?

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet:

```
 modelLite.environments = model.environments

            for k,v in modelLite.environments.iteritems():
                v.grid = dict(copy.deepcopy(v.grid))
```

model.environments is a dictionary mapping strings to Grid objects. (Grid is my custom class) Each Grid object contains a grid attribute, which is a default dict.

In modelLite, I am trying to convert each defaultDict grid attribute to its corresponding dict object.

However, what I find is that the defaultDict object in model.environments are also being cast to dict alongside those in modelLite, despite using copy.deepcopy.

Any advice?

Comment: If you don't want them to be converted to vanilla dictionaries, why `dict`? `deepcopy` will create a new `defaultdict` just fine, it's *your code* that then creates a regular dictionary from it.

Comment: I want those in modelLite to be, not those in model. The issue is both are being converted.

Comment: No, my code should only change those in modelLite, not model

Comment: But they're the *same object*. `modelLite.environments = model.environments` - assignment *does not* create a copy. `deepcopy` is working just fine here.

Comment: To expand on jonrsharpe’s comment, `model.environments` is an *object reference*, a way to refer to a particular object. `modelLite.environments = model.environments` simply creates another reference to that same object. You need a way to make a *copy* of the object.